# How do I transform a parameter in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to process a dataset in Pig, which is available once per day at midnight. Therefor I have an Oozie coordinator that takes care of the scheduling and spawns a workflow every day at 00:00.
The file names follow the URI scheme

```
hdfs://${dataRoot}/input/raw${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}${HOUR}.avro
```

where ${HOUR} is always '00'.

Each entry in the dataset contains a UNIX timestamp and I want to filter out those entries which have a timestamp before 11:45pm (23:45). As I need to run on datasets from the past, the value of the timestamp defining the threshold needs to be set dynamically according to the day currently processed. For example, proessing the dataset from December, 12th 2013 needs the threshold 1418337900. For this reason, setting the threshold must be done by the coordinator.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no possibility to transfrom a formatted date into a UNIX timestamp in EL. I came up with a quite hacky solution:
The coordinator passes date and time of the threshold to the respective workflow which starts the parameterized instance of the Pig script.

Excerpt of the coordinator.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>threshold</name>
    <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -15, 'MINUTE'), 'yyyyMMddHHmm')}</value>
</property>
```

Excerpt of the workflow.xml:

```
<action name="foo">
    <pig>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <script>${applicationPath}/flights.pig</script>
        <param>jobInput=${jobInput}</param>
        <param>jobOutput=${jobOutput}</param>
        <param>threshold=${threshold}</param>
    </pig>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="error"/>
</action>
```

The Pig script needs to convert this formatted datetime into a UNIX timestamp. Therefor, I have writte a UDF:

```
public class UnixTime extends EvalFunc<Long> {

    private long myTimestamp = 0L;

    private static long convertDateTime(String dt, String format)
            throws IOException {
        DateFormat formatter;
        Date date = null;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Illegal Date: " + dt + " format: " + format);
        }
        return date.getTime() / 1000L;
    }

    public UnixTime(String dt, String format) throws IOException {
        myTimestamp = convertDateTime(dt, format);
    }

    @Override
    public Long exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        return myTimestamp;
    }

}
```

In the Pig script, a macro is created, initializing the UDF with the input of the coordinator/workflow. Then, you can filter the timestamps.

```
DEFINE THRESH mystuff.pig.UnixTime('$threshold', 'yyyyMMddHHmm');
d = LOAD '$jobInput' USING PigStorage(',') AS (time: long, value: chararray);
f = FILTER d BY d <= THRESH();
...
```

The problem that I have leads me to the more general question, if it is possible to transform an input parameter in Pig and use it again as some kind of constant.
Is there a better way to solve this problem or is my approach needlessly complicated?

## Edit: TL;DR

After more searching I found someone with the same problem:
http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/125gszzxnx/survey-where-are-all-the-udfs-and-macros

Thanks Gaurav for recommending the UDFs in piggybank.
It seems that there is no performant solution without using *declare* and a shell script.

Comment: Have you tried using UDF CustomFormatToISO (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/CustomFormatToISO.html) to convert a given date (in any format) to date object and then using ISOToUnix (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/ISOToUnix.html) to convert it to epoch?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Pig script into a Python script and pass the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time

from org.apache.pig.scripting import Pig



P = Pig.compile("""d = LOAD '$jobInput' USING PigStorage(',') AS (time: long, value: chararray);
f = FILTER d BY d <= '$thresh';
""")

jobinput = {whatever you defined}
thresh = {whatever you defined in the UDF}
Q = P.bind({'thresh':thresh,'jobinput':jobinput})
results = Q.runSingle()
if results.isSuccessful() == "FAILED":
         raise "Pig job failed"
```